# Checking for overlapping bookings in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a booking table for cars that can be hired. There are multiples cars and multiple bookings. I want to create a query to check for any overlaps (bookings where the same car has been hired and the dates clash) in bookings.

At the moment I have the following query:

```
SELECT bi.id, car_id, booking_id 
from booking_bookingitem bi 
WHERE (
SELECT count(*) FROM booking_bookingitem bt 
WHERE (
date_start - interval '1 days', date_end + interval '1 days'
) OVERLAPS (now(), now() + INTERVAL '30 days') 
AND bt.car_id = bi.car_id) > 1 
ORDER BY car_id, booking_id
```

I have added 1 day offset either side of the start (date_start) and end (date_end) to allow for the car to be returned, cleaned, etc. The 30 day interval is to check bookings 30 days in to the future.

I think I'm close but I am getting some abnormalities when testing.

Can anyone spot what I've done wrong, or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show the output you are currently getting as well as your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare each row with each other and show two overlapping ones in a single result row, example:

```
with booking_bookingitem(car_id, booking_id, date_start, date_end) as (
values
    (1, 1, '2018-05-01'::date, '2018-05-03'::date),
    (1, 2, '2018-05-05', '2018-05-07'),
    (1, 3, '2018-05-11', '2018-05-13'), -- 
    (1, 4, '2018-05-14', '2018-05-16'), -- collision
    (1, 5, '2018-05-21', '2018-05-23')
)

select 
    bi.car_id, 
    bi.booking_id, bi.date_start, bi.date_end,
    bt.booking_id, bt.date_start, bt.date_end
from booking_bookingitem bi 
join booking_bookingitem bt 
on (bi.date_start- 1, bi.date_end+ 1) overlaps (bt.date_start- 1, bt.date_end+ 1) and bi.booking_id < bt.booking_id
where bi.date_start between current_date and current_date+ 30


 car_id | booking_id | date_start |  date_end  | booking_id | date_start |  date_end  
--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------
      1 |          3 | 2018-05-11 | 2018-05-13 |          4 | 2018-05-14 | 2018-05-16
(1 row)
```